# alarms run after phone is rebooted

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

My app is an Sms sender. I wrote a BootCompleteReceiver class, which, after resetting the phone, read the time of sms from the databse and resets the alarms. But the problem here is that most of the time the operation is not done correctly, that is, When the phone is restarted, Alarms are set and immediately run. (SMS is sent). Thank you for your help.

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

SQLiteDatabase          bootDatabase;
String                  DIR_SDCARD    = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String                  DIR_DATABASE  = DIR_SDCARD + "/db-sms_Manager_and_Scheduler/";

ArrayList<setAlarmNode> setAlarmNodes = new ArrayList<setAlarmNode>();


@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            bootDatabase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "/database.sqlite", 0, null);



            //Read From DB
            String name;
            String number;
            String miladiDate;
            String time;
            String message;
            int requestCode;
            String repeat;
            String schedulerId;
            Boolean isFromSmsGroup = false;
            Boolean smsGroup;
            Cursor cursor = bootDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM sms_scheduler where nextOccurrence != '----' ", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while ( !cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                isFromSmsGroup = false;
                schedulerId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("schedulerId"));
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contactName"));
                number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contactPhone"));
                miladiDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nextOccurrence")); /// Notic!
                message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsText"));
                requestCode = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("requestCode"));
                repeat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("frequency"));
                smsGroup = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsGroup")) > 0;

                //calculate Date from next Occurrence
                String nextOccur = getDate(Long.valueOf(miladiDate), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"); /////a ?
                Log.i("TAG", "we are in BootCompleteReceiver and next occur is : " + nextOccur);
                String[] temp = nextOccur.split(" ");
                String nextOccurDate = temp[0];
                String nextOccurTime = temp[1];

                setAlarmNode node = new setAlarmNode();
                node.name = name;
                node.number = number;
                node.nextOccurDate = nextOccurDate;
                node.nextOccurTime = nextOccurTime;
                node.message = message;
                node.requestCode = requestCode;
                node.repeat = repeat;
                node.SchedulerId = schedulerId;
                node.isFromSmsGroup = isFromSmsGroup;
                setAlarmNodes.add(node);
                ///////////////////////////////////setAlarm
                //  setAlarm(name, number, nextOccurDate, nextOccurTime, message, requestCode, repeat, SchedulerId, isFromSmsGroup);

                if (smsGroup) {
                    isFromSmsGroup = true;
                    Cursor cursor3 = bootDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT GcontactName,GcontactPhone,requestCode  FROM sms_group where GschedulerId = '" + schedulerId + "'", null);
                    cursor3.moveToFirst();
                    while ( !cursor3.isAfterLast()) {
                        name = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex("GcontactName"));
                        number = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex("GcontactPhone"));
                        int rCode = cursor3.getInt(cursor3.getColumnIndex("requestCode"));

                        setAlarmNode node2 = new setAlarmNode();
                        node2.name = name;
                        node2.number = number;
                        node2.nextOccurDate = nextOccurDate;
                        node2.nextOccurTime = nextOccurTime;
                        node2.message = message;
                        node2.requestCode = rCode;
                        node2.repeat = repeat;
                        node2.SchedulerId = schedulerId;
                        node2.isFromSmsGroup = isFromSmsGroup;
                        setAlarmNodes.add(node2);
                        ///////////////////////////////////setAlarm
                        //setAlarm(name, number, nextOccurDate, nextOccurTime, message, rCode, repeat, SchedulerId, isFromSmsGroup);
                        cursor3.moveToNext();
                    }
                    cursor3.close();
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();

            }
            cursor.close();

            for (int x = 0; x < setAlarmNodes.size(); x++)
            {

                boolean isFromBoot = true;
                setAlarmNode temp = new setAlarmNode();
                temp = setAlarmNodes.get(x);
                ActivityNewScheduler.setAlarm(temp.name, temp.number, temp.nextOccurDate, temp.nextOccurTime, temp.message, temp.requestCode, temp.repeat, temp.SchedulerId, temp.isFromSmsGroup, isFromBoot);

            }

        }
    });
    thread.start();

}
```

setAlarm:

```
private void setAlarm(final String name, final String number, final String miladiDate, final String time, final String message, final int requestCode, final String repeat, final String SchedulerId, final Boolean isFromSmsGroup) {

String[] nextOccurArrayDate = miladiDate.split("/");
String[] nextOccurArrayTime = time.split(":");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(nextOccurArrayDate[2]));
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.valueOf(nextOccurArrayDate[1]) - 1));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(nextOccurArrayDate[0]));
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(nextOccurArrayTime[0]));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(nextOccurArrayTime[1]));

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(G.context, smsActivityBroadCast.class);
intentAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

intentAlarm.putExtra("NAME", name);
intentAlarm.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
intentAlarm.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
intentAlarm.putExtra("FREQUENCY", repeat);
intentAlarm.putExtra("SID", SchedulerId);
intentAlarm.putExtra("ISFROMSMSGROUP", isFromSmsGroup);
//  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, requestCode, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, requestCode, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

if (repeat.equals("Once")) {
    G.alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
   ;

}
if (repeat.equals("every HALF_HOUR")) {

       G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);

}
if (repeat.equals("HOUR")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("2HOUR")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 2, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("8HOUR")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 8, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("DAY")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("Week")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("Month")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30, pendingIntent);
}
if (repeat.equals("Year")) {
    G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 365, pendingIntent);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that **sending SMSs has a cost**? Just to say.

Comment: @ModularSynth Yes I know.

Comment: ... And you don't care for draining users credits.

Comment: @ModularSynth The user specifies the time, number and recipient of the SMS

Comment: Still they **waste money**. Real money.